# Objective C - How can i define a STATIC array of numbers accessible to all methods in my class?

Tags: objective-c, static-array

How can i define a STATIC array of numbers accessible to all methods in my class???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The same way you'd do it in C:

```
static int myArray[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

If you want a static `NSArray`, you'll have to do some tricks.  `static` isn't allowed for object types in Objective-C (since you can't declare an object directly - only pointers).  In that case, you need to read up on Objective-C singletons.  A quick way to implement it:

```
+ (NSArray *)myArray
{
  static NSArray *theArray;
  if (!theArray)
  {
    theArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
  }
  return theArray;
}
```

You can, of course, set it up to initialize with whatever kind of objects you'd like.